# msysgit 1.7.4 preview fails to install on win xp

Tags: git, window, windows-installer

I'm trying to install 1.7.4 msysgit on WinXP.  Installed it on one system but can't on the other.  When I launch the installer on the 2nd system (a laptop) the installer starts and abruptly terminates with nothing in any logs I could locate or the event viewer.   I tried running the installer as the administrator, disabling encryption on the temp directories and stopping other indexing/backup services that could lock files.

The content of the installer must be OK since I can execute it on my other system.  Elevation cannot be problem since Administrator can't start it either.

Please let me know if you know of anything that might cause this or how I can go about debugging the problem.  If I could just get a debug log I could probably find the cause.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the installer and install with xcopy to a dev/tools folder anywhere you like. Then just add the path or make shortcuts to the exes.

Comment: Ah.  How nice to not have to worry about registry settings and DLL injection into the OS.

Comment: I love having bash on my windows machines. I don't bother scripting in dos or powershell anymore. The bash rocks.

Answer (score -1):

After digging a bit in the msysgit source code, it appears they use InstallShield for the installer.  So to debug it, you'll want to enable InstallShield logging.  Here are some instructions for doing so: http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/4839